# Async / Await with NodeJS + Mongoose doesn't wait

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

Cannot get the async / await functions to work properly in my card game app.

(a) I get the 201 response with no data.

(b) the deck document seems to be created afterwards, with the players field an empty array, indicating it is done after the deck is saved to the mongoDB

Below is my code. Any help is appreciated.

**router.js**

```
router.post('/game', (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { cards, playerNames, attributes } = req.body;

    const newDeck = deck.start(cards, playerNames, attributes);
    res.status(201).send(newDeck);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  };
});
```

**/services/deck.js**

```
 exports.start = async (cards, playerNames, attributes) => {
  try {
    const users = await user.create(playerNames);

    const deck = new Deck({
      cards,
      attributes,
      players: users
    });

    return await deck.save((err, newDeck) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log('RESULT', newDeck);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

**/services/user.js**

```
exports.create = async (users) => {
  if (users.constructor === String) {
    const user = new User({displayname: users});

    return await user.save((err, newUser) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log('NEW USERS ', user);

      return newUser;
    });
  } else if (users.constructor === Array) {
    let userList = [];

    await users.forEach(name => {
      const user = new User({displayname: name.toString()});

      return user.save((err, newUser) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          userList.push(newUser);
          return newUser;
        }
      });
    });
    console.log('NEW USERS ', userList);

    return userList;
  };
};
```

Comment: @AvivLo He is.  Async/Await is one way to manage promises.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say callback.

Comment: Oh, yeah you are right.  The save method doesn't appear to return a promise.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar how you're handling promises,

but `forEach` is not `promise-aware`, that's how it has been designed, so it will not handle your `asynchronous` code properly

replace it with normal `for` loop or `for-of` loop, and add the `await` keyword in front of the `user.save()` method